# Locker Service - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expando' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, lightning-apps, lightning, locker-service

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: title
throws at https://final-bugfix1-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/dpJ3LUIaUXt-CtvrXqBcnQ/aura_prod.js:459:356

I have enabled Locker Service in my org with a lightning app and start getting above error. The initial error was related to loading the JQuery i.e Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expando' of undefined

Somehow this got resolved following:
[Unable to load jQuery in Salesforce Lightning Application after Summer '16 Release](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/125900/unable-to-load-jquery-in-salesforce-lightning-application-after-summer-16-release)

But now stuck with this one. Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128895/locker-service-issue-d3-min-js-library

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using JQuery 2.2.4 version. Infact earlier i was using some older version JQuery version was getting following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expando' of undefined. But after updating to 2.2.4 the above errors is no longer coming and but the new one as mention in this question.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to resolve this error, sharing details here.

After summer 16 release, we need to change the code to include the external JQuery/Css files from static resource. Here is an example of the same:

```
<ltng:require .... scripts="{!$Resource.JQuery}" />
```

Here JQuery is the static resource name, and this static resource is having only single JS File.

For a zip file having multiple files/folder follow another syntax:

```
<ltng:require ....  scripts="{!join(',', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibTwo.js')}" />
```

More details you can find in  following salesforce doc:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm

Answer (score 1):

This error persists:
**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: title throws at .../aura_prod.js:459:356"**

I've opened a [separate thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129993/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-redefine-property-title-throws-at-aura-prod-js) for this.

Answer (score 0):

**This happens when you use old JQuery resource (previous releases from 2016 & earlier).**

Use the latest version of **Jquery.min.js** as resource & issue will be resolved.