# Lightning Component - Locker Service Issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I'm using d3.min.js library in my org. These libraries are being used in lightning component context. this is all working fine till now. After enabling locker service feature it stopped working. Getting below error msg:

Uncaught Error during init [Action failed: c$BaseChartComp$controller$initComponent [TypeError: concreteComponent.getDef is not a function]]

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML'

/resource/D3_3517/D3_3512/d3.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of null

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

**Code Snippet which causes the issue:**

```
getConcreteCompHelper: function(component) {
    var me = this,
        concreteComponent = component.getConcreteComponent(),
        ccHelper = concreteComponent.getDef().getHelper();

    return ccHelper;
},
getConcreteComp: function(component) {
    var me = this,
        concreteComponent = component.getConcreteComponent();

    return concreteComponent;
},
handleWindowResize: function(component) {
    var me = this,
        ccHelper = me.getConcreteCompHelper(component),
        childComp = me.getConcreteComp(component),
        chartRedrawListner = function(cc) {
            return function() {
                ccHelper.drawChart(cc);
            }
        },
        listener = chartRedrawListner(childComp);

    window.addEventListener('resize', listener);

    me.windowUnregisterFn = function() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', listener);
    }
}
```

Application is erroring out while executing line,

```
ccHelper = concreteComponent.getDef().getHelper();
```

Adding screenshot of error message:
[image]

Break point added to show the stack-trace message
[image]

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

This seems unrelated to the JS library you are using. What is most likely happening is the following: a parent component is trying to call a child helper using the verbose approach:

```
var concreteHelper = cmp.getConcreteComponent().getDef().getHelper();
```

We want to remove access to this API because it exposes the complex internal structure of the component. It's hard to test, and hard to maintain.

You need to remove the `.getDef().getHelper()` and replace it with something else. The trick is to declare a method on your concrete component:

```
<aura:method name="myMethod" action="{!c.myMethodHandler}"/>
```

And call it from the super component:

```
component.getConcreteComponent().myMethod();
```

In Lightning, every level of inheritance creates a component. This is a better pattern, since the helper is not part of the public API of a component like a method. You can define the method on an interface and ensure every instance abides to the contract, something that the `.getDef().getHelper();` was not allowing.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Looks like, it encapsulated the component into securecomponent (refer below console output for this statment 'component.getConcreteComponent()'). **SecureComponent: markup://c:StackbarLineChart {29:2;a} {clientBusinessNeedsChart}{ key: {"$c":"c"} }** Before enabling locker service i was getting as **markup://c:StackbarLineChart {29:2;a} {clientBusinessNeedsChart}**

Comment: Ok, here is the situation:

Lightning is different than JS as it creates one instance per level of inheritance. When we design an application, it's the same cost whether your compose (as in include) or you extend another component. 

We will add getConcreteComponent() to SecureComponent and help with this use case, but things will not work as before because getDef() will not be exposed. What you will have to do is create a method on your concrete component and link it to your helper method.

Would that work for you?

Comment: Ok, ConcreteComponent is exposed. I will modify my answer with the proper steps.

Comment: Error **"Uncaught Error during init [Action failed: c$BaseChartComp$controller$initComponent [TypeError: concreteComponent.getDef is not a function]]"** is fixed but getting next error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined throws at /resource/D3_3517/D3_3512/d3.min.js:5:4186"**

Comment: This is the line in d3.min.js referring to **"fo=this.document;if(fo)try{co(fo.documentElement.childNodes)[0].nodeType}catch(so)"**

Comment: Hi Suresh. Can you put a breakpoint to show the stack-trace before getting to the "this.document" (and use a non-monified D3). Which version of D3 are you using? Could you create a small synthetic app to illustrate the problem? I know that I am asking a lot, but I will help you get to the finish line.

Comment: Thanks JF for this follow up. Below are the details, D3.js version (3.5.17). I tried with non-minified version of D3 and it is failing begining of the excecution itself. I have attached screenshot reference (refer top)

Comment: I also just tried using D3 (v3.5.17) in Lightning Component and it is failing with same error in D3 library itself line number 10 `this` is `undefined`. Did you find any workaround to it yet?

Comment: D3 v4 will at least load with no errors using LockerService, but it has major changes that things like Plotly or Highcharts will be slow adopting. In another thread someone from Salesforce mentioned they were working with D3 maintainers...

Answer (score 2):

We have been using D3 in our lightning components and ran into the same error message. We found that, when Locker Service is turned on, "this" in D3's encapsulated function becomes undefined in the Component. We have resolved the issue by defining a variable "self" and assigning "window" to it if "this" is undefined. We then had to update references to "this" in that encapsulated function's scope (not anonymous functions defined within it) to reference "self". Locker Service actually helped us find those instances and after resolving all of them, D3 worked with Locker Service turned on.

Comment: In D3 v3 there was an issue in that library itself that made it's module initialization not function correctly with strict mode (made the assumption in 1 location that this === window). That has been fixed in the latest version of D3 which is 4.2.6 and works find with LS activated.